# How does one subclass an extension locked inside a Pod?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I have Cocoapod library that offers its functionality via an `extension` like this:

```
extension ExposedLibraryClass
{
    class func setup () { ... }
}
```

I have some boilerplate code that goes into `setup()` for every app I do, but each app also needs some bespoke bits adding after that. The problem is that this being an extension, I cannot subclass it, and just wedging bespoke code at the end of the `setup()` function is a very nasty solution.

What would you suggest I do, please? Thank you.

Comment: You can write as many extensions for a type as you like. But you cannot override methods in an extension.

Comment: extensions are _not_ for overriding methods of the original class – as its name says, they are _extensions_ only.

Comment: @MartinR have edited the question so as to make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, extensions can not override methods defined in another extension. They are for adding new functionality to existing objects.

The only way to do what you want would be to create a subclass of SomeClass and override the methods you want.

Take a look at the [documentation on extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) for the list of what they can do.